# character to date time variable in R

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I have a character variable,named date with values like `"2015-10-17T02:00:00"`  I want to convert this to date and time. I used the following,

```
as.POSIXct(format(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

But I am getting, `"2015-10-17 PDT"` I am losing the time factor here. Can anybody help me what mistake I am doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format should reflect the **exact** layout of the data. Your data has "year month day" separated by hyphen, then "T", then "hour minutes and seconds" separated by colon. Your format should show that **exactly**.

```
as.POSIXct("2015-10-17T02:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
#[1] "2015-10-17 02:00:00 EDT"
```

**edit**

The format `"%Y-%m-%d"` can be shortened to `"%F"`, and `"%H:%M:%S"` can be replaced with `"%T"`.

Comment: Now I am able to get the format. I am not able to accept the answer in 10 mins. Would accept it. In the mean time, I tried,

typeof(date) -- > Double

I am getting as double. Can't I get as Date ?

Comment: try `class(date)`. The function `typeof` is pointing to the numbers underneath the data, i.e. "time in seconds from the origin date".

Comment: Thanks... Now i am able to find it.